# @Transactional and Time taken for execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I'm developing a java web application that uses spring like application container. Now while I'm was using the transaction support to spring, I noticed that the time processing of the my annotated method is doubled. Try to descibe the method in a better way:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{

    @Autowired
    UtilService utilService;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void loadContracts(File fileToProcess,UtilDTO dto){

            List<MyObject> objects = utilService.readSomethings("xxx","yyy")

            //I modify Them

           //I save or update  them


    }

}


@Service
public class UtilServiceImpl implements UtilService{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<MyObject> readSomethings(String p1,String p2){

    String queryString =    "from MyObject o where o.param1 = :param1 "
                    + " and o.param2 = :param2 ";

    Query q = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
    q.setParameter("param1", p1);
    q.setParameter("param2", p2);

    return q.getResultList();   


    }

}
```

For example:

The method  **readSomething**  is too late while If I remove the annotation its time processing improves.

Why is there this difference?

Comment: What do you mean by if you remove the annotation? How are you achieving the transaction without the annotation?

Comment: In that case the method is not executed in a transaction

Comment: So again - you leave out a critical piece of your code.  Specifically, the piece that is doing the critical work of loading and modifying the objects.  We can't infer much else from this without actually looking at the code you've used.  Alternatively, you could attach a profiler to this and observe the major pain points on execution.

Comment: You are right but the critical code is the same for both the environment BMT and CMT but the time processing change

Comment: Of course when using transactions or not there is a huge difference in time. Startnig a transaction means allocation a connection, starting a transaction with the database etc. So yes it takes more time, depending on your datasource (connection pool or not) it might be quite fast or really slow (opening a connection is a slow process in general). Basically there will always be a difference, how much depends on a lot of factors and with what you posted here there is no way in answering that.

Answer (score 1):

The performance is likely due to you creating a new transaction and suspending the existing transactions every time that method is invoked.

From the [documentation on `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW), emphasis mine:

> Create a **new transaction**, and **suspend the current transaction** if one exists. Analogous to the EJB transaction attribute of the same name.

Unless you have specific requirements about creating a new transaction for this method, I would recommend letting it fall through to default behavior - that is, `Propagation.REQUIRED`.

Comment: I already try with Propagation.REQUIRED but i get the same result

Comment: The likelihood then is that you've got some other issue going on with the performance of your code, not necessarily due to the transaction.  I know that suspending transactional sessions and spinning up a new one/tearing it down is expensive, but the rest of your code could be just as expensive, if not costlier.  There's not much else I could suggest with the not-really-a-snippet posted above.